# Powercenter Informatica Using a Oracle View as Source

Tags: plsql, informatica-powercenter

I have an Informatica PowerCenter process that uses as Source (VIEW_SOURCE) and ORACLE View and as Target a normal database table.

The VIEW_SOURCE has normally about 500k/600k rows.

My problem is: The data from the VIEW_SOURCE is not inserted on totally on the Target Table. Some data, that exists, doesnt' go into table.

The PowerCenter process doesn't end in error, and there is no error in process.

Is possible, for instance, that we got a problem "rendering the source view", like a memory leak?

Comment: There is no rejected rows. There is no filter or transformations, is a direct bulk insert from the View to target table. About the logging level is set to "NONE".  Another info, that can be relevante: the workflow executes more sessions in parallel, and each on  has a VIEW as soruce and a table as target, with no transformations in the middle.

Comment: Well, when i go the the Workflow Monitor and check the session log of my session there is nothing wrong, all normal without error.  For instance, when i have  a "Connection Failure", i can checkit on Session Log. So i guess it is logging something.

Comment: Take the source query PowerCenter fires against the database from session log, and run it manually from your query tool (sqldeveloper, SQLPLUS etc). Check if you are getting all the expected data.

Comment: Yes, i'm Samik. The data is the same. I'm getting all the data

Comment: Please post a screenshot from the Monitor with number of affected and applied rows.